# applet's parent container not set up

Tags: java, web-applications, applet, appletviewer

I am calling an applet from a web application. And it is working fine in my machine for JRE Versions like 1.6,1.7 & 1.8.0.31. And the same is not getting in our client machine. While running it shows the below exception.
Any idea to resolve the below error.

```
applet's parent container not set up
```

Comment: `applet's parent container not set up`  IS that literally a copy/paste of the info. in the console?  I'm not familiar with that error.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Yes Mr. Andrew. It is the error getting in the console.

Comment: Is it being loaded by JS?  Post the HTML.